# How is this array legal?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

In [CoreAudioTypes.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/musicaudio/reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html), there are the following declarations:

```
struct AudioBuffer
{
    UInt32  mNumberChannels;
    UInt32  mDataByteSize;
    void*   mData;
};
typedef struct AudioBuffer  AudioBuffer;

/*!
    @struct         AudioBufferList
    @abstract       A variable length array of AudioBuffer structures.
    @field          mNumberBuffers
                        The number of AudioBuffers in the mBuffers array.
    @field          mBuffers
                        A variable length array of AudioBuffers.
*/
struct AudioBufferList
{
    UInt32      mNumberBuffers;
    AudioBuffer mBuffers[1]; // this is a variable length array of mNumberBuffers elements
} ;
typedef struct AudioBufferList  AudioBufferList;
```

My question concerns the `mBuffers` member of `AudioBufferList`.  They declare it as an array of size 1, yet it is used as if it were (any size) as dictated by `mNumberBuffers`.

Isn't this illegal in C and C++ (the code should work in both)?

This code:

```
int m[1];
m = new int[ 40 ] ;
```

Doesn't work in C++, so what gives?

#### Edit

Here's usage:

```
bufferList = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(
  sizeof (AudioBufferList) + sizeof (AudioBuffer) * (channelCount - 1) ) ;
```

So, interpreting this with the answers below, the array of size 1 there acts like an array.. but there are *more than 1* element[(s)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/20684/111307) in the array `mBuffers`.  What an odd hack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, it's certainly legal to declare an array with one element as a struct member. Accessing elements beyond element 0 is not *illegal* (in the sense that a compiler is not required to diagnose it as an error), but doing so has undefined behavior. But since it's a common idiom, known as the "struct hack", as long as you allocate enough memory to hold the additional elements, it's very likely to work.

The 1999 ISO C standard added a new feature, the *flexible array member*, intended to replace the struct hack but to have well defined behavior. A flexible array member is declared with empty square brackets `[]`.

The situation is similar in C++ -- except that C++ never adopted flexible array members. (the usual advice for C++ is to use some container class (such as `vector`) rather than raw arrays.

Question 2.6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) discusses the struct hack.

Comment: How do you distinguish "illegal" from "undefined behaviour"?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The C standard doesn't use the term "illegal"; I generally use it to refer to violations of constraints and syntax rules.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I would define "Illegal" to mean a compiler error: C will not let you do this. Undefined Behavior on the other hand occurs at runtime.

Comment: @Valek: Actually there's nothing that says undefined behaviour can only result in symptoms at run-time; strictly speaking it could turn your compiler into a hairdryer when you feed your program into it. Anyway, it looks like you use "illegal" to mean "ill-formed".

Comment: @Keith Thompson Does the _flexible array member_ need to be the last field?  Sorry, to bother - looked up more and found that it does. [Using sizeof with arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Using_sizeof_with_arrays)

Comment: Great answer man.  I still don't get why people wouldn't just declare the array separately and normally (ie declare `AudioBuffer * mBuffers`), instead of using this "hack" -- (usage now listed in my question).  Seems more awkward than useful.

Comment: @bobobobo: The advantage is that the array is allocated contiguously with the rest of the structure, and you can copy or deallocate the whole thing without worrying about maintaining the pointer and dealing with a separately allocated object (as long as you keep track of the size and length).

Answer (score 3):

It's technically illegal, or at least invokes undefined behaviour, but GCC will let you do it safely because it supports the related [Zero-Length Array](http://www.c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html) technique [as an extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html#Zero-Length).

Typically you'd follow that technique and use an array dimension of `0` for this task, but the end result is basically the same.

In C++ you should be using a vector; the dynamic allocation really isn't going to be problematic except in the rarest of circumstances.

Comment: The code in the question defines an array of length `1`, not `0`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, I'm aware of that, but the extension allows both this code and that found in the zero-length array example. Further, the zero-length array example is the canonical way to do what the OP describes, so it's entirely relevant.

Comment: In what sense are zero-length arrays "canonical"? The classic struct hack very commonly uses an array of length 1, as in the code in the question; this has the considerable advantage of not being a constraint violation. In C99 and later, flexible array members are what I'd call 
"canonical".

Comment: @Keith It's still a constraint violation, though at least it is not two.

Comment: Zero-length arrays are forbidden. See 6.7.6.2 (C11) or 6.7.5.2 (C99): "In addition to type qualifiers and the keyword static, the [ and ] may delimit an expression or *. ... If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have **a value greater than zero**."

Comment: An array of length 1 is not a constraint violation (it's perfectly valid), nor is accessing it beyond element 0 (that has undefined behavior, but it's very likely to work). What constraints are violated?

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: They're not *forbidden*; they're a constraint violation. A conforming compiler can issue a non-fatal warning and accept such an array. A non-conforming compiler (as gcc is by default) can do anything it likes.

Comment: @Keith: The two are indistinguishable. Zero-length arrays are forbidden in compliant programs. Yes, okay, this doesn't mean you're "forbidden" for ever writing them in some "Like C++" language, or that your wife will withhold your dinner if you do it. You seem to be picking hairs for no reason...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Not at all. If zero-length arrays were actually *forbidden*, gcc would not be able to offer them as an extension. A conforming compiler **may not** accept a program with an unconditional `#error` directive; it **may** accept a zero-length array declaration as long as it warns about it. That's hardly "indistinguishable".

Comment: @Keith: No. A program with `#error` in it is a program written in C++, deemed ill-formed in that language due to a specific rule. Extensions produce "nearly C++" languages that are not even intended to be compliant to the standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: This question is tagged both C and C++. The C standard explicitly permits conforming compilers to support extensions (N1570 section 4, paragraph 6). C++ does as well in 1.4p8: "A conforming implementation may have extensions (including additional library functions), provided they do
not alter the behavior of any well-formed program. Implementations are required to diagnose programs that
use such extensions that are ill-formed according to this International Standard. Having done so, however,
they can compile and execute such programs."

Comment: There are languages (such as Ada) that require conforming compilers to *reject* programs that violate language rules. C and C++ do not; they only require "diagnostics", which may be mere warnings. That's an important distinction, and it's the one I was making above.

Answer (score 2):

It's the *'struct hack'*; it usually works, not least because it was the main way to handle the business before C99 established 'flexible array members' using the related but distinct notation:

```
struct AudioBufferList
{
    UInt32      mNumberBuffers;
    AudioBuffer mBuffers[];
};
```

Such types cannot be elements of an array (though their pointers can appear in an array, of course). For all practical purposes, such structures must be dynamically allocated.

This is not a feature of standard C++, though the GNU C++ compiler does support it.

The 'struct hack' is not formally portable and is not standardized.